# Including Python.h in C++ with a Makefile

Tags: python, c++, makefile, g++

I have the following Makefile and I need to add Python.h to my main.cpp file. No matter what I try or search I can't seem to figure out how to get Python.h imported properly using the Makefile. I've installed python properly, and I have my files named properly. Python 2.7 lives in the following folder as expected: `/usr/include/python2.7`

The only important part of main.cpp is where I include Python with:

```
#include <Python.h>
```

And my Makefile currently looks like this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LIBS=-lwiringPi

all: my_code_file

single_chan_pkt_fwd: secondary.o main.o
    $(CC) main.o secondary.o $(LIBS) -o my_code_file

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp

secondary.o: secondary.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) secondary.c

clean:
    rm *.o my_code_file
```

When I run the command `make` on the command line, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:26:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
```

Could someone help me out with the Makefile addition that would be needed in my case? I'm running all this on a Raspberry Pi, if that helps in any way.

Based on similar questions on Stack Overflow, I have already tried this (which runs fine but doesn't help):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: To add a new directory to your include-path, put  -I/the/directory/where/python.h/is/located into your CFLAGS variable (replace the path after -I with the Python.h file's actual location, of course... and btw that is dash-capital-eye, not a dash-lower-case-ell, in case your browser's font makes it hard to tell which letter it is)

Comment: You sir, are a saint. I never tried including it in my CFLAG variable so I never got it to work. It works as expected now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS with the `python-config` (or `python3-config`) utility.

```
%> python3-config --cflags
-I/path/to/Python3.6.5/include/python3.6m -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
%> python3-config --ldflags
-L/path/to/Python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/path/to/Python-3.6.5/lib -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lrt -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

In your Makefile, perhaps set them like this:

```
PY_CFLAGS  := $(shell python3-config --cflags)
PY_LDFLAGS := $(shell python3-config --ldflags)
```